# How can I find the number of bytes of a variable that contains URL data

Tags: python

I want to get the number of bytes returned from a URL request, that I get using the **urllib**. It returns the byte array (I guess, I'm not sure). If so, how can I get the number of bytes of the variable that contains the URL?

```
import sys
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.imgur.com/fyxDric.jpg') as f:
    a = (f.read())
    print(a)
```

Comment: Have you tried `len()`?

Comment: Oh. I didn't try `len()`. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best way, but maybe a way:

```
import re, sys, urllib, requests

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.imgur.com/fyxDric.jpg') as f:
    a = str(f.read())

print(len(re.findall(r'\\x.+?(?=\\x|$)', a)))
```

#### Output

```
490266
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VP3c1P/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VP3c1P/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: I just used `len()` and got the size. The size I'm getting is 804329.